# How to submit manually a form inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

i have a view in my app who is displaying an iframe.

In that iframe there is a form from another application coded in standard javascript and i want to be able to submit it manually from my controller.

Here is what i am trying to do in my controller:

```
var login = function(){
  var form= $document.find('formInsideIframe');
  var userName = $document.find('#inputForUserName');
  var password = $document.find('#inputForPassWord');

  userName.value = 'root';
  password.value = 'password';

  form.submit();
};

login();
```

Unfortunately nothing is happening even if i am able to log the form...

How can i do that?

Comment: What is `forceLogin`, is it in the iFrame JS scope? Your question needs more content. If you are accessing the frame element from parent, you need to use `window.frames['iFrameName'].document.getElementById`

Comment: forceLogin is the form itself located inside the iframe. May be i should said that the form don't have any id

Comment: Put a breakpoint a debug is my best suggestion. Second best, post a link to your app and let us have a look.